# QBS: Module qt/core could not be loaded

Tags: c++, linux, qt, package

Trying to collect qutim 0.3.2 (qt5) project (https://github.com/euroelessar/qutim) with qbs:

```
[22:30:49][anton@arch-Laptop: qutim]$ qbs build profile:qt5
No build graph exists yet for this configuration.
Resolving project for configuration qt5-debug
ERROR: /home/anton/qutim/core/3rdparty/k8json/k8json.qbs:8:5 Module qt/core could not be loaded.
```

qbs compiled from aur (qbs-git)

Archlinux x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write "Qt" in dependencies in .qbs file with capital letter:

```
Depends { name: "Qt.core" }
```

Or it's convinient to write that way with few dependence modules:

```
Depends { name: "Qt"; submodules: ["core", "gui"] }
```